# Why are Lwaxana Troi and Reginald Barclay not present at Deanna Troi and Will Riker's wedding in Nemesis?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-nemesis

Why are Deanna Troi's mother and Mr. Barclay not present at her wedding ceremony portrayed in *Star Trek: Nemesis*? By the end of Voyager, Troi and Barclay seem to get along pretty well, and Lwaxana is... well, her mother. Will's father is not present either.

Is there an in-universe explanation? Is there a real-world explanation? Were the characters even considered for participation?

Comment: I disagree, I'm asking about Troi's wedding in general, the answers for the questions might be related.

Comment: I think you should split this into two questions since they aren't directly related. For the record, I'm reasonably sure that Majel Barrett was producing Andromeda in Vancouver (and hence unavailable for filming) and Dwight Schultz was possibly in Japan doing voice-work for Final Fantasy X.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

- The absence of Lwaxana Troi isn't clearly explained in universe. However, since there was a second ceremony planned on Betazed, this one following Betazoid traditions, it would seem logical that Lwaxana was on Betazed, being busy making sure everything is perfect.
- As for Reginald Barclay, I couldn't find any explanation to his absence. Although, while he was good friend with Troi, he was still clearly not at ease in social situations, as shown clearly even in Voyager episodes. It's quite possible that he sent his best wishes for the wedding but declined to come since there would quite a crowd at the wedding.

Comment: WRT Barclay: he had put a fair amount of effort into helping Voyager get home, as I recall. Assuming something like real time passing between that and the wedding, he may have felt it was more important to be involved in what was going on with that crew than to go to Deanna's wedding - especially as he'd had a crush on her, at one point.

Comment: @RDFozz, That's not true, the star date for the film is at a later date in relation to Voyager's return for at least many months.

Comment: These seem like educated guesswork, but guesswork nonetheless

Comment: @RDFozz Star Trek Nemesis is set in 2379 while Voyager ends in 2378. Thus it's been at least a year since Voyager got home.

Comment: I like to think Barclay spent the day in a holodeck simulation, besting Riker in physical combat and taking Troi for his own bride. But I’m a bit weird.

Comment: An easy explanation might be that Barclay, like most Starfleet officers, don't always have the luxury to take shore leave/vacation whenever they want. He may have been on a mission far away, or on a time/resource-sensitive operation.
As with real-life weddings, attendance isn't always possible for a plethora of reasons.

Comment: @Apollo - even assuming a year or more, there was probably a lot of debriefing to do. The Voyager crew had not only met alien races, but had seen a lot of new technology; I'm sure Starfleet wanted to dig into that. As someone involved with Voyager locally, Reg, may have been the perfect choice for working with the crew on recording, implementing, and integrating the tech into Starfleet's standard repertoire. With time for real safety precautions and testing procedures that could easily be a years-long project.

Comment: Did Majel Barett voice any computers in *Nemesis*??